# SQL like tools for linux - Scan files and work on CAT and ECHO commands

Tags: sql, linux, shell

I found some cool tools like [q](https://github.com/harelba/q) they are giving the flexibility to use SQL on top of files.

Im looking for some tools like this but they can work even on the cat and echo commands.

#### EX:

`file.txt`  will be like this.

```
id name 
1 aaa
2 bbb
```

The tool may work like

```
cat file.txt | sqltool select * from output
```

Still, I'm not able to find something like this. If anyone knows please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice list of command line SQL tools on the [Structured Text Tools](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#sql-based-tools)
github repository.